# Getting the domain name

Tags: c, macos

Other than `getdomainname()` is there any other way to get the domain name on a Mac using C?

I can use alternatively Cocoa APIs.
Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `getdomainname()`? I'd imagine most other APIs would simply call it anyway.

Comment: I found that in certain computers in out network it doesn't work and I was wondering if there is an alternative I can use in case this one fails.

Comment: Could it be that on these "certain computers" you should look into hostname instead?

Comment: already doing that. I'd appreciate it if you could answer the question I asked (if you know the answer). I don't think it's a complicated question. I just haven't found an answer, hence I asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the DNS name that corresponds to the local system, I don't think `getdomainname()` is your friend. According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getdomainname.3.html), this is for obtaining the *NIS* domain name of a system:

```
 Getdomainname() returns the standard NIS domain name for the current
 host, as previously set by setdomainname().  The parameter namelen speci-fies specifies
 fies the size of the name array.  The returned name is null-terminated
 unless insufficient space is provided.
```

And in fact, it's largely accurate to say that a host doesn't *have* a DNS domain name.  Each interface on your system has an address, and there *may be* a DNS record that resolves to that address, but the truth is that (a) there may *not* be a corresponding DNS record, and (b) there may be a DNS record that resolves to your host *and to other systems as well*.  For example, the hostname "google.com" resolves to a slew of difference addresses:

```
$ host -t A google.com
google.com has address 74.125.226.244
google.com has address 74.125.226.240
google.com has address 74.125.226.241
google.com has address 74.125.226.242
google.com has address 74.125.226.243
```

And of course your system may have multiple IP addresses associated with it (e.g., both wired and wireless).

If you're willing to cross your fingers and hope, your best bet is usually to determine your local ip address via a call to `getsockname()` on an open connection, and then do a reverse DNS lookup on that address to find a corresponding name in DNS.

Comment: I see how I can get the local IP using `getsockname`, but how do you get the hostname from that? gethostbyname?

Comment: As you might expect, `gethostbyname()` expects a hostname as input.  You have an address, so you want `gethostbyaddr()`.